# IOS Swift3 - How to save array of custom object in CoreData?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

First of all, I have array of custom object, [XXX].

In CoreData, I set Banners to "Transformable" and "@NSManaged public var banners: NSObject?"

When I save like this ->>

```
    saveData.banners = [XXX] as NSObject

    DataController.shared.saveContext()
```

But it's error ->>

```
<NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6000001d95f0>
 2017-09-12 22:03:49.381 xxxx[6056:71337] *** NSForwarding: warning: object                  
 0x60000011f920 of class 'xxxx.Banners' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
 Unrecognized selector -[xxxx.Banners replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver:]
```

Comment: are the objects xxx of type NSObject?
try -> class xxx: NSObject{ ... }

Comment: Shouldn't that be:
saveData.banners = [XXX] as NSManagedObject

Comment: Try to make banners of type [XXX] like:
@NSManaged public var banners: [XXX]? and then 
saveData.banners = [XXX]

Answer (score 0):

Transformable attributes only work if the data conforms to `NSCoding`. Core Data can't magically transform every possible data object into something it can store, you need to tell it how. If you have an array of objects that conform to `NSCoding`, then the array will conform.